# Probability - Amount of money in pocket

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution

The amount of money a student in the Accounting Department has in his pocket is a random variable that follows the normal distribution, with an average price of $30$ euros and a variance of $100$.

a) What is the probability that a student has $25$ to $35$ euros in his pocket?

b) If we randomly select $25$ students, then what is the probability that a student has less than $20$ euros in his pocket?

c) How much money does $75\%$ of students have in their pocket?

$$$$

I have done the following :

a) We have that the standard deviation is equal to $\sqrt{100}=10$.

Do we have to use the $z$-score?

$$$$

**EDIT :**

We have that $Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}=\frac{X-30}{10}$.

Then \begin{align*}P(25\leq X\leq 35)&=P(X\leq 35)-P(X\leq 25)\\ & =P\left (Z\leq \frac{35-30}{10}\right )-P\left (Z\leq \frac{25-30}{10}\right )\\ & =P\left (Z\leq 0.5\right )-P\left (Z\leq 0.5\right )\end{align*} Is that correct so far?

Comment: "follows the normal distribution" so presumably the $z$ score or something else based on the normal distribution

Comment: Could you take a look at the edited part of my question? @Henry

Comment: You have a sign error when you write $=P\left (Z\leq 0.5\right )-P\left (Z\leq 0.5\right )$ and should have $=P\left (Z\leq 0.5\right )-P\left (Z\leq -0.5\right )$